# Calibrating turtlebot odometry without gyro/imu

Tags: imu, calibration, turtlebot, gyro, create-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the turtlebot stack to control my Irobot Create + Kinect, but currently do not have a gyro. However, I would like to calibrate the odometry from the Icreate encoders. The turtlebot calibrate routine however requires an imu present: I keep getting the error "Still waiting for imu" when trying to run the calibration routine.

Does anyone know a way to calibrate the Irobot Create odometry without needing the imu present? I've looked into the code of calibrate.py a bit and do not see an easy way of removing the imu dependency..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10868/calibrating-turtlebot-odometry-without-gyro/imu/) by [Marco](https://answers.ros.org/users/920/marco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2011-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a good point.. I have created a ticket (https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/52) to make this possible. In the future it will check the has_gyro param. I'll try and get to it this week.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-24**:
released in diamondback and electric! turtlebot_apps 0.1.14 and 0.2.1

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-11**:
worked on it this weekend, I think I have a working solution I still need to test it before I push it out but I hope to have it out in the next stable release

**Comment by [Marco](https://answers.ros.org/users/920/marco/) on 2011-09-08**:
Great, thx! I'll check back next week.

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-08**:
Sorry Marco, I haven't had time, but I will make time this weekend.

**Comment by [Marco](https://answers.ros.org/users/920/marco/) on 2011-09-07**:
Any progress on this?

**Comment by [Marco](https://answers.ros.org/users/920/marco/) on 2011-08-15**:
Great! I hope you'll be able to fix this.